How to prove this inequality which is like mean value inequality?
Suppose $a, b, c, t \in [0,1]$ and $a-b>b-c>0$. Consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x\geqslant0, y\geqslant 0} \frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{\left(1-x\right)\left(a-c\right)-t\left(b-c\right)}+\frac{\left(1-y\right)^2}{\left(1-y\right)\left(a-c\right)-t\left(b-c\right)}\\
s.t. x+y=z \text{ with } z \leqslant 1-t.
\end{equation*}
Numerical simulation suggests the minimum is achieved when $x=y$. I tried to prove this by proving
$\frac{\left(1-x\right)^2}{\left(1-x\right)\left(a-c\right)-t\left(b-c\right)}$ is strictly convex. But I got lost after taking the derivative twice. I was wondering whether there is a more elementary/convenient way of proof since this looks like a mean value inequality.
